# Having problems to deploy to Heroku Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm, heroku

Im having trouble with production for my app to heroku.
the log im getting when trying to push from node git:

```
Counting objects: 100% (194/194), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (185/185), done.
Writing objects: 100% (194/194), 703.98 KiB | 4.96 MiB/s, done.
Total 194 (delta 70), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 18.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 18.13.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.19.3
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        added 984 packages, and audited 985 packages in 38s
remote:
remote:        40 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        29 vulnerabilities (8 low, 18 moderate, 3 high)
remote:
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > proshop@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! While resolving: react-paypal-button-v2@2.6.3
remote: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
remote: npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
remote: npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1 || ^18.0.0" from @react-aria/ssr@3.4.1
remote: npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-aria/ssr
remote: npm ERR!     @react-aria/ssr@"^3.2.0" from @restart/ui@1.4.1
remote: npm ERR!     node_modules/@restart/ui
remote: npm ERR!       @restart/ui@"^1.4.1" from react-bootstrap@2.7.0
remote: npm ERR!       node_modules/react-bootstrap
remote: npm ERR!         react-bootstrap@"^2.7.0" from the root project
remote: npm ERR!   16 more (@restart/hooks, @restart/ui, @testing-library/react, ...)     
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote: npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x || 17.x.x" from react-paypal-button-v2@2.6.3
remote: npm ERR! node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2
remote: npm ERR!   react-paypal-button-v2@"^2.6.3" from the root project
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
remote: npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote: npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x || 17.x.x" from react-paypal-button-v2@2.6.3
remote: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2
remote: npm ERR!     react-paypal-button-v2@"^2.6.3" from the root project
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
remote: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.   
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.luihn/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.luihn/_logs/2023-01-10T23_16_50_967Z-debug-0.log       
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: fc7ab23b834a092ca743dc214dafdda32868ba40
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 
fc7ab23b834a092ca743dc214dafdda32868ba40
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code 
from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to ikproshop.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/ikproshop.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ikproshop.git'
```

**And my code is this file**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PayPalButton } from 'react-paypal-button-v2';
// import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Message from '../components/Message';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import {
  getOrderDetails,
  payOrder,
  deliverOrder,
} from '../actions/orderActions';
import {
  ORDER_PAY_RESET,
  ORDER_DELIVER_RESET,
} from '../constants/orderConstants';

const OrderScreen = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const orderId = id;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails;

  const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay);
  const { loading: loadingPay, success: successPay } = orderPay;

  const orderDeliver = useSelector((state) => state.orderDeliver);
  const { loading: loadingDeliver, success: successDeliver } = orderDeliver;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  if (!loading) {
    // Calculate prices
    const addDecimals = (num) => {
      return (Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    };
    order.itemsPrice = addDecimals(
      order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0)
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
      const { data: clientId } = await axios.get(`/api/config/paypal`);
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`;
      script.async = true;
      script.onload = () => {
        setSdkReady(true);
      };

      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    if (!order || successPay || successDeliver) {
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_RESET });
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_RESET });
      dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId));
    } else if (!order.isPaid) {
      if (!window.paypal) {
        addPayPalScript();
      } else {
        setSdkReady(true);
      }
    }
  }, [
    dispatch,
    orderId,
    successPay,
    successDeliver,
    order,
    navigate,
    userInfo,
  ]);

  const deliverHandler = () => {
    dispatch(deliverOrder(order));
  };

  const successPaymentHandler = (paymentResult) => {
    dispatch(payOrder(orderId, paymentResult));
  };

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : error ? (
    <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
  ) : (
    <>
      <h1>Order {order._id}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Shipping</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Name: </strong> {order.user.name}
              </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Email: </strong>{' '}
                <a href={`mailto:${order.user.email}`}>{order.user.email}</a>
              </p>

              <p>
                <strong>Address:</strong>
                {order.shippingAddress.address}, {order.shippingAddress.city},{' '}
                {order.shippingAddress.postalCode},{' '}
                {order.shippingAddress.country},
              </p>

              {order.isDelivered ? (
                <Message variant='success'>
                  Delivered on {order.deliveredAt}
                </Message>
              ) : (
                <Message variant='danger'>Not Delivered</Message>
              )}
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Payment Method</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Method: </strong>
                {order.paymentMethod}
              </p>
              {order.isPaid ? (
                <Message variant='success'>Paid on {order.paidAt}</Message>
              ) : (
                <Message variant='danger'>Not Paid</Message>
              )}
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Order Items</h2>
              {order.orderItems.length === 0 ? (
                <Message>Order Is Eempty</Message>
              ) : (
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                  {order.orderItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col md={1}>
                          <Image
                            src={item.image}
                            alt={item.name}
                            fluid
                            rounded
                          />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                          <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>
                            {item.name}
                          </Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                          {item.qty} x ${item.price} = ${item.qty * item.price}
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  ))}
                </ListGroup>
              )}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Items</Col>
                  <Col>${order.itemsPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Shipping</Col>
                  <Col>${order.shippingPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Tax</Col>
                  <Col>${order.taxPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Total</Col>
                  <Col>${order.totalPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              {!order.isPaid && (
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  {loadingPay && <Loader />}
                  {!sdkReady ? (
                    <Loader />
                  ) : (
                    <PayPalButton
                      amount={order.totalPrice}
                      onSuccess={successPaymentHandler}
                    ></PayPalButton>
                  )}
                </ListGroup.Item>
              )}
              {loadingDeliver && <Loader />}
              {userInfo &&
                userInfo.isAdmin &&
                order.isPaid &&
                !order.isDelivered && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Button
                      type='button'
                      className='btn btn-block'
                      onClick={deliverHandler}
                    >
                      Mark as Delivered
                    </Button>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default OrderScreen;
```

**My package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "proshop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MERN shopping cart app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "node": "18.6",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
  },
  "author": "Idan Kfir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "heroku": "^7.67.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Now the bug from what im seeing is with the react-paypal-button-v2 not working along with react version 18.2. **(fix me if im wrong)**
I tried to use another paypal buttons without changing the context too much but I failed over and over again. even tried with chatGPT to codeReview it and help me change to another framework but it meant changing the whole client id config and such. is there any easy fix for that with a framework which is easier and maybe contact with my code and my sdk that I implement already?
Thanks in advance hope I didn't say too much.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer, I had to remove all the paypal checkouts from my dependencies at package.json at the frontend.
also deleted them from node_modules.
Writing this for anybody else who runs with issues with the react-paypal-buttons-v2.